# Wordpress website redirecting to some anonymous links

Tags: php, wordpress, security, plugins, wordfence

My new WordPress website seems to be redirected to some anonymous links and i installed wordfence plugin and start scanning and there found some errors and those fixed also. But currently in wordfence scan my website is perfectly okay. But the redirecting issue still continues...is there any other way to finding out where the malicious files are hiding

need to find where the malicious files are present

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.